# To cut after certain word in unix

Tags: unix

```
Hi all,

    i have a text file containing details as shown below.i want to extract host and port from the text and paste it in other txt file
```

1. (PROTOCOL=NIL) **(HOST=123.256.36.20) (PORT=1256)**
2. (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(PROTOCOL=NIL)
   **(HOST=123.256.36.23)(PORT=1256))**
3. (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(PROTOCOL=NIL)
   **(HOST=COLIN1-IMP.COM)(PORT=1566)**(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(PROTOCOL=NIL) **(HOST=COLIN2-IMP.COM)(PORT=1586)**
4. (PROTOCOL=NIL) **(HOST=123.256.36.25) (PORT=1526)**

**Required Output:**

> 1. 123.256.36.20:1256
> 2. 123.256.36.23:1256
> 3. COLIN1-IMP.COM:1566
> 4. COLIN2-IMP.COM:1586
> 5. 123.256.36.25:1526

**Code Used:**

```
cat for2.txt | perl -ne 'print "$1=$2\n" if(/HOST=([\w.]*.'-'*[\w.]*.).*PORT=(\d+)/)' > in.txt
sed 's|[()]||g' in.txt > in1.txt
```

by using perl i got the Host and Port values..by using sed i removed the '()'..

**Obtained output:**

> 1. 123.256.36.20 =1256
> 2. 123.256.36.23=1256
> 3. COLIN1-IMP.COM=1586
> 4. 123.256.36.25 =1526

perl is not getting the **COLIN2-IMP.COM** which is present in the same line as **COLIN1-IMP.COM**

help me ..thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for my doubt and i like to share it with you all..

```
cat sample1.txt | perl -nle 's{HOST=([^)]*).*?PORT=([^)]*)}{print "$1:$2"}ge' > sample2.txt
```